# Scala default TypeTag

Tags: generics, default, scala-option

I'm using typetags in Scala to match options

```
def foo[T: TypeTag](bar: Any) = {
  bar match {
    case option: Option[T] => option match {
      case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[List[Any]] => println("List Option")
      case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Map[Any, Any]] => println("Map Option")
      case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Boolean] => println("Boolean Option")
      case _ => println("String")
    }
    case _ => println("no Option")
  }
}
```

So when I use the function this way

```
foo[List[Any]](val)
```

all will be fine and the output is "List Option" in this case.
But when I try to use it without the TypeTag

```
foo(val)
```

the outputs is "List Option", regardless of whether it's a Option[List[Any]] or Option[String].

So now my question: 
Is it possible to define a default value for my TypeTag T?
I want to use my function without the TypeTag if it is not needed and then the output should be "String" and not "List Option".
It is possible to define a default value for parameters, so maybe it is for TypeTag too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the type `T` is not related to the type of the parameter `bar`.

This means, if you don't add the the type explicitly, the compiler will infer `Nothing` because it has no further information.

`Nothing` is a subtype of everything, so your subtype checks succeeds in the first branch already (in fact all your cases are true for `Nothing`).

Your code could be "improved" like this:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
def foo[T: TypeTag](bar: Any) = {
  bar match {
    case option: Option[T] => option match {
      case x if typeOf[T] =:= typeOf[Nothing]       => println("Nothing")
      case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[List[Any]]     => println("List Option")
      case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Map[Any, Any]] => println("Map Option")
      case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Boolean]       => println("Boolean Option")
      case _ => println("String")
    }
    case _ => println("no Option")
  }
}
```

I say "improved" because one should never ever write code like this. It feels like it tries to shoehorn some idiom from untyped languages into Scala.

Comment: Really, don't write code like this. Not even like in my "solution".

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo[T: TypeTag](bar: Any)
```

is just

```
def foo[T](bar: Any)(implicit tt: TypeTag[T])
```

So you can provide a default value:

```
def foo[T](bar: Any)(implicit tt: TypeTag[T]=...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way was the solution.

I wrote another function.
Now if I need TypeTags I can use fooType else I can use foo.

```
def foo(bar: Any) = {
  fooType[String](bar)
}

def fooType[T: TypeTag](bar: Any) = {
  bar match {
    case option: Option[T] => option match {
      case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[List[Any]] => println("List Option")
      case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Map[Any, Any]] => println("Map Option")
      case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Boolean] => println("Boolean Option")
      case _ => println("String")
    }
    case _ => println("no Option")
  }
}
```